# How to apply column before vimdiff

Tags: bash, vimdiff

if I have 2 files, file_a and file_b, how can I vimdiff the two files after applying column -t to both of them.

Comment: `column -t file_a > file_a_col; column -t file_b > file_b_col; vimdiff file_a_col file_b_col`?

Comment: thanks. ideally, I am looking for a way to do that without creating additional files

Comment: Process substitution `<()`? e.g. `vimdiff <(column -t file_a) <(column -t file_b)`

Comment: that is exactly what I was looking for, thanks. Feel free to add as an answer

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? If you don't want to create additional files, any *changes* you make in `vimdiff` will be lost. If you only want to *view* diffs, `diff` itself offers plenty of options (including `--side-by-side`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html):

```bash
vimdiff <(column -t file_a) <(column -t file_b)
```